# Memory visibility when a pointer to an object is passed to std::thread as argument

Tags: c++, multithreading

Let's say there is a simple class `Counter` which contains a integer member `count`. A new object of `Counter` is constructed and `count` is initialized to some number.

Now, if I pass a pointer to this object to a new thread as an argument, would the new thread always and instantly see the value that was initialized in the main thread? If so, how is it happening that a different thread is able to see updates made by the main thread without any explicit synchronization?

```
class Counter {
public:
 int count = 0;
} 

void print(Counter* counter) {
  std::cout << counter.count;
}

int main() {
  Counter* cPtr = new Counter();
  cPtr->count = 10;

  pThread = new std::thread(print, cPtr);

  // Assume that the program does not quit until the above
  // thread has finished.
  pThread->join();
}
```

[Another e.g. from `folly` documentation](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/io/async/README.md):

```
EventBase base;
auto thread = std::thread([&](){
  base.loopForever();
});
```

`base` is being used in a different thread. How is it ensured that that thread sees all the initialized fields of `base` object correctly?

Apologies if this question sound too basic but I wasn't able to find an answer.

Comment: All threads in a single process share the same memory map, the memory map is *per process* not per thread. So memory allocated in one thread is available to every other thread in the same process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronization doesn't mean "update" for the parameter.
If you have a variable shared between threads and this variable is set to a value from a thread, all the other threads will see the same value.

Synchronzation is about *knowning* or *expecting* the change of the value. 
If you have a thread that sets a variable, other threads must not attempt to set it at the same time for example or this will lead to UD on the variable's actual value.

But, since all threads share the same memory, "updating" the value is not needed.

Variable V. Thread A sets V to 1. Thread B reads V *after* being set by A, it will have the value of 1. The question is *when* Thread B should read the variable (that is, *after* A has set it) - that's the point of synchronization.

Comment: `If you have a variable shared between threads and this variable is set to a value from a thread, all the other threads will see the same value.`: I thought, if the data is shared b/w two threads, it needs some sort of mechanism to make changes visible to other threads immediately like `volatile`, `atomic` etc.

Comment: @RandomQuestion You need synchronization to *access* the share memory, to protect against *data races*. But since the memory is shared, there's nothing stopping the "sharing" of data between threads (in the same process).

Comment: @RandomQuestion, no, it's the same shared memory. Sync is to protect from data races. If you don't need to protect from a data race, you don't need any manual synchronization.

Comment: @RandomQuestion Regarding `volatile`, please see [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4558031/440558).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need a mechanism which makes the `int count;` visible to other threads because it just resides on memory, pointer says the address of the resource so anything who has a pointer to the `int count` can see what resides in it ( there could be some special cases ). So it is natural and comes free.

Syncronization is a different topic and it is not made to see updates immediately. It is generally made to access/update the resources in synchronized to prevent creating race conditions, etc.