# Safe to use object constructed earlier in a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-barriers

Suppose my code is like the following:

```
struct Foo {
  Foo() : x(10) {}
  int x_;
}

void WillRunInThread(const Foo* f) {
  cout << "f.x_ is: " << f->x_ << endl;
}

struct Baz {
  Baz() : foo_(), t_(&WillRunInThread, &foo_) {}
  Foo foo_;
  std::thread t_;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Baz b;
  b.t_.join();
}
```

Am I guaranteed that `WillRunInThread` will print 10? I have seen [some StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60202349/1431244) that indicate this is safe. However, I'm not sure that's the case. Specifically, I think the following two possibilities exist both of which could create issues:

1. `Foo.x_` could be stored in a register when `t_` is started.
2. The compiler could re-order some instructions. While C++ guarantees that `foo_` will *appear* to be constructed before `t_` that's only within the same thread. The compiler is free to, for example, re-order the initialization of `foo_.x_` until after `t_`.

I see no indication that `std::thread`'s constructor acts as a memory fence of any kind to prevent the above two issues. However, I see code like the above quite frequently which makes me think I'm missing something. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a mistake to think in terms of implementation details like "this variable may be stored in a register" or "the compiler may want to reorder these instructions". Stick to what the standard tells you.

There is a synchronization point when a thread starts (C++17 [thread.thread.constr]/6):

> The completion of the invocation of the constructor synchronizes with the beginning
> of the invocation of the copy of `f`.

"A synchronizes with B" means that all side effects that have been completed before A (in A's thread) will be visible to all code that runs after B (in B's thread). See [intro.races]/9-12.

In particular, if thread 1 starts a thread using the `std::thread` constructor, and thread 2 is the thread that starts and its initial function is `f`, then any code inside `f`, or inside a function called from `f`, will see all side effects that were caused by thread 1 prior to executing the `std::thread` constructor.

Since the initialization of `foo_.x_` is sequenced before initialization of `t_`, it follows that the value of 10 will be read by the new thread.

Comment: The "completion of the invocation of the constructor synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of f" bit is what I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your code as written is certainly safe. (ignoring errors: missing `;`s, `x` instead of `x_`). This is because **`foo_` is actually copied into the `thread` constructor**. You can see this by adding `Foo(const Foo&) = delete;`, and it will fail to compile.

> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread
> The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value.

Now, to get at the spirit of your question, let's change the thread initialization to

```
  Baz() : foo_(), t_(&WillRunInThread, std::ref(foo_)) {}
```

This is **still safe**, because:

> The completion of the invocation of the constructor *synchronizes-with* (as defined in [`std::memory_order`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)) the beginning of the invocation of the copy of *f* on the new thread of execution.

Comment: yes, thanks. I missed that the thread constructor acts as a synchronization point. Also missed that `Foo` is being copied in my example. Will fix that. Thanks.